# Logic behind memory leak in android

Tags: android, memory

Normally in c++ what memory leak is , If we have alloted an object like

`Obj c = new Obj();`

then if we do

`c = b;  (example)`

we lose the pointer to the object `c` that's the memory leak.

**Question:**

But in android Garbage collector collects object when there is no pointers pointing to them. So why there is memory leak even after that ?

**Update**

All the answers points to holding reference to unused objects is causing memory leak. Thats right. But is that the only cause of memory leak. Holding pointers will be released when activity is finished unless it is static. There are bitmaps and other memory hunger objects , don't they cause any problems in this

Comment: http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx. and there is talk on memory management and at the end there is talk on memory leaks and how to use mat tool http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: an object would be garbage collected once it goes out of scope..memory leak happen if such object's are being referenced by others mainly static fields

Answer (score 1):

In garbage collected runtimes, a memory leak means that an object cannot be collected even if it is no longer used. For example, a reference is held to an object but the reference is no longer used for anything.

Casually, the term memory leak is used to refer to situations where these incollectible objects keep on accumulating, increasing the allocated heap size and eventually leading to OOM.

Comment: No that can be handled if there is less instance variable. Strong references are not pointing to memory leak(The term is leak not held). But i hear the term memory leak more frequently. Some one who knows  better can explain that, and iam curious to learn that.

Answer (score 1):

In Android/Java memory leak occurs

- when you are keeping the **reference** of an object/instance even after it is no longer required.
- when you keep open a **file stream**, when you are done with it.
- Unclosed **connections**

There are other reasons for memory leak as well, but these are the `most common ones`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to define "**Memory Leak**" in the first place. Memory leak is something you don't need anymore but it still in the memory and each time a new object is created, a new place will be allocated in the memory. The application will hold more and more memory in time.

```
private static Drawable background;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);

  background = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);

  label.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

Above example, TextView get Activity as reference, which is a link between

**TextView** and **Activity**

now, then there is a static variable

**background**

which holds the background drawable, static variable will be alive until the application is destroyed or finished. Imagine that you want to destroy the activity, when you destroy static variable will still hold a link to activity, because of that garbage collector won't be able to collect it.

You can have a look at [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) about more.

Comment: scope of static variable is all along the application, Thats not causing any memory leak . Is nt it? But it will released as the program ends or process is dead. The term is then different, Why is it memory leak. Thanks for your help also

Comment: I think we need to define "Memory Leak" in the first place. Memory leak is something you don't need anymore but it still in the memory, and each time you create a new activity, memory will hold new one as well in the memory. in above example, you destroyed activity, that means you don't want this in your memory but it's still there, you are actually holding a memory which shouldn't be. That should be definition of memory leak. In your example, GC already collects c value from the heap, that's not causing any memory leak actually.

Comment: Yeah, Holding reference is a memory leak but that can be reduced by using low scope objects. But there are other factors that cause memory leak, Since we cant directly release the memory as in c++ there may be some ways

Comment: I forgot to mention the real reason to be honest, every time you create another activity, new activity will hold another place in the memory, as you see, you'll allocate more memory than before, so go on, more and more each time, that's a memory leak.

Comment: sorry i didn't get that point. As we allocate memory continously for each activity, do you mean the sum is increased or each allocation is weirdly increased ?

Comment: the sum is increased, and each time a new activity is created, let me put it in another way, GC collect c value in your example, because it has no link to anywhere, but what if a variable links to this value? GC won't collect it, but you don't know that and you allocate a new memory, and each time when you create a new one, sum will be increased

Comment: yeah thats cool :) Let me put this question ON , May be some guys have lot more info about this

Answer (score 1):

There might be a leak when a Context (an Activity, Service, etc.) is retained by any helper class that would have a reference to it.

Illustration: instead of this:

```
public class Helper {

    private static Context mContext;

    public Helper(Context context){

        mContext = context;
    }

    public static void methodDoesSomething(){

        ...
    }
}
```

Use the context without retaining it by passing it as a parameter:

```
public class Helper {

    public static void methodDoesSomething(Context context){
        ...
    }
}
```

Because Android will want at some point to destroy an Activity for instance, and an object has a reference to it, The Garbage collector can not remove that Activity thus we have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is partially in your question: Precisely because those references are not freed. Suppose a situation where you have an instance of a class, you've ended working in it but for certain circumstances, the instance keeps there in a state it's not freed. Additionally to Garbage Collector unability to free it, if not controlled, the amount of memory may even increase if it's not handled.

There is one additional thing too. You may have a code that looks correct and well written, but when you instantiate some native libraries, that means you're referencing an hierarchy of classes. If you're not aware of what are you doing, you may precisely handle incorrectly some references and lead to memory leaks. One very popular example is keeping a `Context` reference into your class. The context instance is never freed and a reason of huge memory leaks.

There are solutions for this, additionally to the obvious (free objects when you're done, etc.). In Java there are `SoftReferences`, `WeakReferences`, and other. This objects are containers that tell the Garbage Collector that they have preference on being freed once unused or there are no other references pointing to them. So you're helping the GC to know what should be freed. They're dangerous at a certain point in Android environments, as apps are limited too 16MB of heap, so a `WeakReference` might be collected too fast. It's necessary to check whether the object still exists.

Comment: Yeah, I read those kind of things , since we release the pointers we dont need to worry about garbage collection of those objects. I just updated my question a bit more

Comment: The update basically references to my second phrase. It's about instantiating Java/Android native classes and calling a hierarchy of classes. They should be freed when unused, but handled incorrectly may lead to memory leaks.